# Dynamics 365 : Exporting default customization is not bringing up all the fields including the unmodified ones

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am trying to download default customization for CRM Online (Dynamics 365 - 8.2). I have noticed that some of the fields for most (if not all) custom entities are not present in customization.xml.

I have created a small CRM solution with only the missing fields for some entities. I exported the solution and found out that all the fields have an extra attribute **unmodifield="1"** associated with them. I suspect that this is the reason why the fields are missing in the customization.xml when exporting the default solution.

Has any one encountered the problem? Can you recommend a way so that the default solution includes all the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one answered I am just listing down the work around I have to come up with for this problem.

I worked off a theory that unmodified="1" comes up for the attributes that has not been changed since the last publish. So I manually initiated an update for all the fields for all the entities. The easiest way to do this is to come up with a tool that toggles audit setting for all the fields. Very much like [bulk attribute updater](https://github.com/MscrmTools/XrmToolBox/wiki/Attribute-Bulk-Updater) in the XrmToolBox except I am doing it for every entity and for every fields.

Note the toggle tool does not update audit settings for all the fields. Fields like primary key and OptionValueName will not be updated with audit setting toggle.